# How to document a sequence diagram

Tags: report, document, sequence-diagram

How to document (describe) a sequence diagram in a technical report? Is there any guidelines for that?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the UML templates.... Draw events as downward sloping lines instead of horizontal.

Horizontal lines mislead the mind into thinking that no time passes between the event being sent and the even being received.

I have on several occasions previously redrawn anothers sequence diagram in this manner, and looked for pathological cases where events can "cross in the mail" so to speak....and uncovered a bug.

[Message Sequence Chart GENerator](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen) is a handy tool.

Comment: You didn't understand me, what I meant was that when I put a sequence diagram in a report (MS Word document) as a figure, I will describe it by writing a paragraph. What should I put in that paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

`Sequence diagrams` represent your `use-cases`. Documentation for the `sequence diagram` is the corresponding `use-case` description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various online and offline tools to generate clean and comprehensive sequence diagrams easily. Some of them are:

[Visual Paradigm](https://online.visual-paradigm.com/diagrams/solutions/free-sequence-diagram-tool/), [Figma](https://www.figma.com), [StarUML](https://staruml.io/), and [SequenceDiagram.org](https://sequencediagram.org/)